# MYSQL table merging

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to merge these two tables by the column C

**Table 1:**

```
A B C
a b 1
c d 2
e f 3
```

**Table 2:**

```
C D E
1 G H
4 I J
5 K L
```

**Combined:**

```
A B C D E
a b 1 G H
c d 2 0 0
e f 3 0 0
0 0 4 I J
0 0 5 K L
```

I don't think the join function works because it won't leave you with all 5 results for Column C?

Comment: removed, overlooked that the left table is also empty for some values ;)

Comment: What about LEFT JOIN + RIGHT JOIN + UNION. Maybe like this `(SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ...) UNION (SELECT ... RIGHT JOIN ON t1.c = t2.c AND t1.c IS NULL). Would give you all with both and all with right one NULL in the first part and all with left one NULL in the second part.

Comment: Select distinct on C somehow together with a join?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked in my test:

```
(SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, COALESCE(t2.d, 0), COALESCE(t2.e, 0)
    FROM t 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t.c = t2.c) 
UNION 
(SELECT 0, 0, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e
    FROM t2 
    LEFT JOIN t ON t2.c = t.c 
    WHERE t.c IS NULL)
```

Test data:

```
Table 1
a  b  c
1  0  1
2  2  2

Table 2
c  d  e
2  0  2
3  0  3
```

Result

```
a  b  c  d  e
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  2  0  2
0  0  0  3  3
```

Comment: try converting NULL value into zero by using **COALESCE**

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example to do [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join) but MySQL (AFAIK) can't do that:

Sample data:

```
create table tab1 (A char(1), B char(1), C int);
insert into tab1
select 'a', 'b', 1 union all
select 'c', 'd', 2 union all
select 'e', 'f', 3;

create table tab2 (C int, D char(1), E char(1));
insert into tab2
select 1, 'G', 'H' union
select 4, 'I', 'J' union
select 5, 'K', 'L';
```

`Full outer join` would look like this:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.A, '0') as A, 
    coalesce(t1.B, '0') as B, 
    coalesce(t1.C, t2.C) as C, 
    coalesce(t2.D, '0') as D, 
    coalesce(t2.E, '0') as E
from tab1 t1
full outer join tab2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c;
```

Result (SQL Server):

```
A    B    C           D    E
---- ---- ----------- ---- ----
a    b    1           G    H
c    d    2           0    0
e    f    3           0    0
0    0    4           I    J
0    0    5           K    L
```

And workaround is to do`union` of `left join` and `right join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.A, '0') as A, 
    coalesce(t1.B, '0') as B, 
    coalesce(t1.C, t2.C) as C, 
    coalesce(t2.D, '0') as D, 
    coalesce(t2.E, '0') as E
from tab1 t1
left join tab2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c
union
select coalesce(t1.A, '0') as A, 
    coalesce(t1.B, '0') as B, 
    coalesce(t1.C, t2.C) as C, 
    coalesce(t2.D, '0') as D, 
    coalesce(t2.E, '0') as E
from tab1 t1
right join tab2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c;
```

Result (MySQL):

```
A   B   C   D   E
--- --- --- --- --- 
a   b   1   G   H
c   d   2   0   0
e   f   3   0   0
0   0   4   I   J
0   0   5   K   L
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use UNION rather than JOIN.

See [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) for a good explanation.